# Strategy for implementing a composite key of which the second part is rarely discriminating. Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5, composite-primary-key, identity-column, sql-server-ce-4

I have the following scenario:

An  `Atom` Entity is usually unique and can be stored in the database using a single `AtomID` field as its primary key.`. In rare cases the`Atom`needs to be split. In that case a second record must be created in the database table with an identical`AtomID`but a discriminating`SplitID`.

So, basically I need a composite key of `AtomID` and `SplitID` where the `SplitID` will rarely be discriminating. I would hate to lose the AutoID feature that the SQLServerCompact4 database offers, but that is what happens when I define a composite key for the `Atom` Entity in the Fluid API.

What is the best approach for this problem?

Comment: "a second record must be created in the database table" You mean the Atom table? So the split has the same fields?

Comment: When the table is originally populated or added to, the `Atoms` are unique. An error later on may however cause the necessity to splt the atom in two different records, which of course will have differenet values for their other fields. But is paramount that I can see that the records once were one.

Comment: I don't see any other way than a self-referencing FK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a new table with foreign key , `AtomID` and the discriminating `SpiltID` to show the relation between the two.

Comment: Wouldn't that require using a Join every time I want to query the Atoms table? That seems inefficient given that an Atom will rarely be split.

Comment: I implemented it this way. We will see what it does to performance.